# How to create new h and m file in Xcode6

Tags: ios, xcode6gm

I downloaded Xcode6 and create a simple project.When i choose objective C option from new file template it creates a file name with .m extension.I do not know how to create new .h and .m file in Xcode6.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`CMD + N -> iOs -> Cocoa Touch -> Objective-C Class`

Answer (score 5):

To create a Objective-C class, you have to select **"Cocoa class"**. This will create an .h and .m file for you. Alternatively you can manually add a "Header file" with the same name, but thats just more work for the same thing.